# How to get balances of all the accounts(~1000) in Geth node?

Tags: go-ethereum, balances, rpc

How can I get the balance of all the accounts in my Go Ethereum node? I have about 1000 accounts and it is too slow to use `eth_getBalance` to get balance for each address. Are there any ways to use curl and rpc?

Answer (score 0):

Any library or other script you use will ultimately end up at `eth_getBalance`.

You could feasibly put together a script that can check multiple addresses in paraller via `eth_getBalance`, since your bottleneck is unlikely to be the actual balance call.

Alternatively, you could consider using multiple nodes via providers such as infura or etherscan to spread out your queries.

Answer (score 0):

Ethereum address balances are public information, so you don't have to obtain them from your own node.  There are publicly accessible databases storing them.  One example is [etherscan.io](https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=balance&address=0xde0b295669a9fd93d5f28d9ec85e40f4cb697bae&tag=latest&apikey=YourApiKeyToken).  Another is [Google BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/introducing-six-new-cryptocurrencies-in-bigquery-public-datasets-and-how-to-analyze-them).  Both are able to handle thousands on requests per second.